# What does algebraic multiplicity mean for compact operators

Tags: functional-analysis, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, spectral-theory, trace, compact-operators

Im trying to understand Lidskii Theorem which states the following.

> If $H$ is a separable Hilbert Space, $T:H \rightarrow H$ a (compact) trace class operator and $\{\gamma _n\}_{n\in \Bbb N}$ are the eigenvalues of $T$, each repeted as many times as its algebraic multiplicity, then
>   $$Trace(T)= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \gamma_n$$

And I couldn't find anywhere the definiton of algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue in the infinite dimensional case. I started believing it has something to do with the following statement. Let $T:H \rightarrow H$
 be a compact operator, for every eigenvalue $\gamma$ there exist a $m\in \Bbb N_0$ such that
$$\{0 \} \subsetneq Ker(T-\gamma.Id)\subsetneq Ker(T-\gamma.Id)^2 \subsetneq \dots\subsetneq Ker(T-\gamma.Id)^m=Ker(T-\gamma.Id)^{m+1}=Ker(T-\gamma.Id)^{m+2}=\dots$$
I thought $m$ was the algebraic multiplicity of $\gamma$ but then realiced this does not match with the definition in the finite dimensional case, for example, taking $T=Id_{\Bbb R^2}$ and $\gamma=1$. So my question, again, is "what does algebraic multiplicity means?"

Comment: First, the definition of algebraic multiplicity is the same as in the finite-dimensional case. Second, you should probably consider the Jordan block decomposition to understand the above definition.

Comment: Well, any linear function function between finite dimensional spaces is compact so $Id_{\Bbb R^2}$ is compact. The definition I have for the finite dimensional case is the multiplicity of $\gamma$ as root of the caracteristic polynomial. In the infinite dimensional case, we don't have caracteristic polynomial so I don't understand how to use the same definition

Comment: I would guess that he really means the geometric multiplicity :) At least the statement of the theorem would make more sense then. Note that the statement is already wrong in the finite dimensional case.

Comment: Nono, I mean algebraic multiplicity, geometric multiplicity is $dim(K-\gamma .Id)$ and its not what de theorem states. I dont see why the statement is wrong in the finite dimensional case, for me its completely true

Comment: See here: https://tqft.net/web/teaching/2013/Analysis3/Assignments/Essay-example.pdf Page 7: Apparently one can define $\det (I + z A)$ for a trace class operator A, and this can be used to define what algebraic multiplicity means.

Comment: I believe that is a consequence of the theorem, not a definition. Could work as a definition anyway, but tensor products scares me so I was trying to avoid them. I was reading "Peter Lax - Functional Analyisis" proof but he omits many details (and doesn't talk about algebraic multiplicity, don't know why). Thanks for the Help!

Comment: [This old question of mine is very strongly related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/137468/8157).

Comment: The textbook Linear Algebra Done Right by Sheldon Axler is motivated by the goal to remove the determinant as much as possible. It gives a (finite dimensional) treatment of eigenvalues that is independent of the determinant, and defines multiplicity in terms of generalized eigenvectors in the same way as the accepted answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **algebraic multiplicity** of an eigenvalue $\gamma$ of $T\in\mathcal L(X)$, where $X$ is a Hilbert space, equals $\dim \cup_{k=1}^\infty \ker(T-\gamma I)^k$, which in the case of a compact operator equals $\dim \ker(T-\gamma I)^m$ for the $m$ in your question.

The latter holds because 1. clearly always $\ker(T-\gamma I)^m\subset \ker(T-\gamma I)^{m+1}$, and 2. for compact operators there exists a maximal $m$ such that the "$\subset$" is "$\subsetneq$".

Corresponding vectors are called **generalized eigenvectors** (of order $k$, where $k$ is minimal).

**References**

This and the fact on compact operators is stated on p. 24, section 1.4.2 of Finite Element Methods for Eigenvalue Problems, by Jiguang Sun, Aihui Zhou, CRC Press, 19.8.2016 - 343 pp. (By p. 18, X is a Hilbert space.) Link to page 24: https://books.google.fi/books?id=YC7FDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA24

Theory and Applications of Volterra Operators in Hilbert Space,
by Israel Gohberg, M. G. Krein, p. 49, footnote 30 states the same for $\gamma\ne0$:
https://books.google.fi/books?id=HUkR9eQhKLYC&pg=PA49

Note: $(T-\gamma I)^m = T^m -\gamma T^{m-1} + \cdots +(-\gamma)^m I=T'+(-\gamma)^m I$, where $T'$ is compact. Therefore, the algebraic multiplicity of a nonzero eigenvalue of a compact operator is always finite (use Rudin F.A., Theorem 4.25a). (That of $0$ may be infinite; take $T=0$.)

BTW, "analytic multiplicity" may be different from the algebraic and geometric ones. "Geometric multiplicity" is $\dim \ker(T-\gamma I)$, hence at most the algebraic one.

Edit: much the same is said here, including a proof for the existence of a maximal $m$ (still assuming a Hilbert space; I haven't checked if it is necessary): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/406371